# Access Windows mobile Address book

Tags: c#

What is the code for accessing contacts from address book in windows mobile application when the contacts are stored into the windows mobile address book?

I tried:

```
(Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.OutlookSession ss = new OutlookSession())
{
    ContactCollection mobilePhoneBook = ss.Contacts.Items;
    foreach (Contact aContact in mobilePhoneBook)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("First Name: " + aContact.FirstName.ToString()
            + "\n Mobile Number: " + aContact.MobileTelephoneNumber.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

It's giving the error:

> `can't find pinvoke dll 'pimstore.dll'`

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an article](http://milandinic.blogspot.com/2009/02/c-windows-mobile-api-for-contacts.html) specifying on how to access contacts in WinMo

I'll summarize the methods specified

1. Add a Namespace:
   using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook;
2. Add an Assembly:
   Microsoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook
3. Access the contacts

   OutlookSession mySession = new OutlookSession();
       ContactCollection collection = mySession.Contacts.Items;
       foreach (Contact contact in collection)
       {
       //do something with contact details, e.g. write to file or update
       }

[Here is the namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.pocketoutlook.aspx) that will be most useful to  you